# Does my system clock automatically sync to the hardware clock?

Tags: time, clock

I know my hardware clock is based on a simple quartz clock and will go out of sync over time, but system time is based on the CPU clock and is super accurate as a result.

I'm not in an environment where I can use NTP so I need to know, will the system clock *automatically* sync back to the hw clock to keep it from drifting?

If it doesn't, I'll need to set up a cron job or something to call `hwclock` to sync back to the hw clock. Everything is set to UTC so that shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [this page](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Clock-2.html) provides the best answer:

> ## 2. How Linux Keeps Track of Time
>
> ### 2.1 Basic Strategies
>
> A Linux system actually has two clocks: One is the battery powered
>   "Real Time Clock" (also known as the "RTC", "CMOS clock", or "Hardware
>   clock") which keeps track of time when the system is turned off but is
>   not used when the system is running. The other is the "system clock"
>   (sometimes called the "kernel clock" or "software clock") which is a
>   software counter based on the timer interrupt. It does not exist when
>   the system is not running, so it has to be initialized from the RTC
>   (or some other time source) at boot time. References to "the clock" in
>   the ntpd documentation refer to the system clock, not the RTC.
>
> The two clocks will drift at different rates, so they will gradually
>   drift apart from each other, and also away from the "real" time. The
>   simplest way to keep them on time is to measure their drift rates and
>   apply correction factors in software. Since the RTC is only used when
>   the system is not running, the correction factor is applied when the
>   clock is read at boot time, using clock(8) or hwclock(8). The system
>   clock is corrected by adjusting the rate at which the system time is
>   advanced with each timer interrupt, using adjtimex(8).
>
> A crude alternative to adjtimex(8) is to have chron run clock(8) or
>   hwclock(8) periodically to sync the system time to the (corrected)
>   RTC. This was recommended in the clock(8) man page, and it works if
>   you do it often enough that you don't cause large "jumps" in the
>   system time, but adjtimex(8) is a more elegant solution. Some
>   applications may complain if the time jumps backwards.
>
> The next step up in accuracy is to use a program like ntpd to read the
>   time periodically from a network time server or radio clock, and
>   continuously adjust the rate of the system clock so that the times
>   always match, without causing sudden "jumps" in the system time. If
>   you always have a network connection at boot time, you can ignore the
>   RTC completely and use ntpdate (which comes with the ntpd package) to
>   initialize the system clock from a time server-- either a local server
>   on a LAN, or a remote server on the internet. But if you sometimes
>   don't have a network connection, or if you need the time to be
>   accurate during the boot sequence before the network is active, then
>   you need to maintain the time in the RTC as well.